# TLS (HTTPS) on Server with Angular Universal

Tags: angular, express, server-side-rendering, angular-universal

I'm playing around with Angular Universal right now. Now I have a problem for which I have not found any documentation.
I created my project (build: ssr), loaded it on my server, started Node and called the page in the browser. It's going well. However, I can't find a way to activate https.
In the "server.ts" I tried the following:

```
const server = require('https').createServer(credentials, app);
server.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Node Express server listening on http://localhost:${port}`);
});
```

Unfortunately without success. Node was starting - no error. The server was listening. But the page loads into the blank - no error (timeout at some point). Can someone help me?

Thx, Flo

Answer (score 1):

Oh, that was stupid of me.

The error was simply that I did not call the export "App Function" on createServer. This is how it is correct and works:

```
createServer (App ());
```

What two brackets can do :-)

Good night!